# Server Error in '/' Application after build solution in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, sitecore, tds

Im trying to sync my projects with Sitecore database but when I build the solution provided by Sitecore Learning (Clothing Company), my website is not loaded and an error appears. It was working fine before I try to build it.

```
`Server Error in '/' Application.
Could not load type 'Sitecore.HealthCheck.DependencyInjection.HealthChecksBuilder' from assembly 'Sitecore.Kernel, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Sitecore.HealthCheck.DependencyInjection.HealthChecksBuilder' from assembly 'Sitecore.Kernel, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Sitecore.HealthCheck.DependencyInjection.HealthChecksBuilder' from assembly 'Sitecore.Kernel, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.]
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.DependencyInjection.ContentSearchServicesConfigurator.AddContentSearchHealthChecks(IServiceCollection serviceCollection) +0
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.BaseServicesConfiguratorFactory.Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection) +171
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.BaseServicesConfiguratorFactory.Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection) +171
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.BaseServiceProviderBuilder.ConfigureServiceCollection() +142
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator.ConfigureServiceProvider() +225
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator.get_ServiceProvider() +513
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.SitecorePerRequestScopeModule..ctor() +13

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +142
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +107
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +1476
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) +186
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture) +28
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.CreateNonPublicInstance(Type type, Object[] args) +80
   System.Web.HttpApplication.BuildIntegratedModuleCollection(List`1 moduleList) +234
   System.Web.HttpApplication.GetModuleCollection(IntPtr appContext) +1153
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +139
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +168
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +277
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +369

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +532
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +111
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +724`
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at error, it seems the Sitecore.Kernel.dll is getting replaced with different version in your website bin or your web.config file is getting replaced which might be having different assembly binding version info for Sitecore.kernel.dll.

I would suggest, check the Sitecore.kernel.dll version from your original website bin, in dotpeek.
Update Sitecore.kernel.dll of this version in your project solution via Nuget manager or update your DLL in your managed lib folder or DLL location folder.

Keep the assembly binding info in solution web.config as same as in the original web.config if you have.

If the DLL version is same both the place already, then load the Sitecore.kernel.dll in dotpeek, check for class Sitecore.HealthCheck.DependencyInjection.HealthChecksBuilder if there or not. If not, then some config file is having an entry for this class. Search word HealthChecksBuilder in App_config folder files, and comment the setting where you find and see if the site is up or not.

Then VS publish hope the issue gets resolved.